# Como hago para que me reconozca codigo javascript dentro de razor

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 <script>

            var nombre_opcionArray = [];
            var accesos_opcionArray = [];
            var menu_actual = "";
        

            if (codigo_user != "ADMIN") {
                @foreach(var item in listado_opciones)
                {
                    nombre_opcionArray.push(@item.opcion.Trim());
                    accesos_opcionArray.push(@item.acceso_op.Trim());
                 }
                    $(".ocultar_menu").each(function () {
                        var nombre_menu = $(this).data("nombremenu");
                        debugger;
                        if (nombre_menu.indexOf("ó")) {
                            nombre_menu = nombre_menu.replace(/\ó/g, '&#243;');
                        }
                        if (nombre_menu.indexOf("á")) {
                            nombre_menu = nombre_menu.replace(/\á/g, '&#225;');
                        }
                        var id_el_menu = $(this).attr("id");
                        var pos_arr = nombre_opcionArray.indexOf(nombre_menu);

                        if (pos_arr >= 0) {
                            if (accesos_opcionArray[pos_arr] == "S") {
                                $("#" + id_el_menu).removeClass("ocultar_menu");
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }
            else { 
                $(".ocultar_menu").removeClass("ocultar_menu");
    }

        </script>
```

Pero me sale error al intentar añadir en el arreglo nombre_opcionArray y accesos_opcionArray de JavaScript. ¿Como podría arreglar este problema? Saludos, desde ya, gracias

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: @gbianchi Lo que pasa, es que toma los valores de los arreglos de javascript como razor, ya que está dentro del ciclo for de razor . El error es el siguiente el nombre_opcionArray no existe en el contexto actual, es como si tuviera que declararlo como razor o C# y no reconoce el arreglo como JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre la solución: es agregar la etiqueta   codigo javascript . Les dejo ejemplo:

```
     @{if (codigo_user != "ADMIN")
                {

                   foreach(var item in listado_opciones)
                    {
                    <text>
                    nombre_opcionArray.push('@item.opcion.Trim()');
                    accesos_opcionArray.push('@item.acceso_op.Trim()');
                    </text>
                    }
                    <text>
                        $(".ocultar_menu").each(function () {
                            var nombre_menu = $(this).data("nombremenu");
                            if (nombre_menu.indexOf("ó")) {
                                nombre_menu = nombre_menu.replace(/\ó/g, '&#243;');
                            }
                            if (nombre_menu.indexOf("á")) {
                                nombre_menu = nombre_menu.replace(/\á/g, '&#225;');
                            }
                            var id_el_menu = $(this).attr("id");
                            var pos_arr = nombre_opcionArray.indexOf(nombre_menu);

                            if (pos_arr >= 0) {
                                if (accesos_opcionArray[pos_arr] == "S") {
                                    $("#" + id_el_menu).removeClass("ocultar_menu");
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    </text>


                }
                else
                {

                 <text>
                    $(".ocultar_menu").removeClass("ocultar_menu");

                 </text>
                }

              }
```

Comment: Un ejemplo ayudaría pues es tiene muy poco contexto tu aporte

Comment: Por favor leer [answer]. La respuesta es muy escueta, es como si alguien respondiera: *tu error es la forma en que tienes escrito tu programa*. Eso ni es una respuesta ni ofrece contexto. Saludos

Comment: Ok, edite la respuesta